# Changed /etc's permissions on Guix 0.14.0 (GNU/Linux); now unable to login

Tags: linux, permissions, gnu

I have a laptop (Asus X553MA) running purely [GNU Guix System](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/) 0.14.0.

I naively changed the permissions of /etc by executing:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc
```

-then tried to 'correct' the mistake with something like:

```
chmod -R 644 /etc
```

(Obviously I am a complete novice and did not understand the importance of permissions within the GNU/Linux framework...)

As a consequence, user login now fails completely, stating **"Failed to execute login command"**, and then returns me to the login screen.

From there, pressing *ctrl+alt+f2* allows me to access some kind of terminal/shell, but upon user "login", I'm simply regarded as:

```
I have no name!@laptop
```

Still, I then tried using `sudo` (/`su`) and `chmod` to see if I could alter /etc's permissions to some kind of workable state, but unfortunately `sudo` (/`su`) cannot even function, among other commands, as they are not even recognized without correct access to some file(s) within /etc, presumably:

```
I have no name!@laptop ~$ sudo
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

So, my questions:

- Is there a way to get `sudo` working, given improper permissions for
  /etc?
- Is there a clever way to get /etc to a state where I can at least
  login?
- Is it possible to boot from a flash-drive and edit /etc's permissions?

I realize I've done a terrible thing and will likely have to reinstall all my packages/programs individually to fix this.  However, I need basic access to my computer first.

-Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uggh.
I see you are a novice, so I will post some high level solutions here. Pick one that makes sense to you. Feel free to ask for more details.

1. Reload the operating system.
2. Use grub/bootloader to boot in single user mode. You will need the root or grub password for this.
3. Try to login as root. sudo/su won't work. Do you have the root (admin) password?
4. Boot from your CD/DVD. Mount your hard drive under /mnt and change the permissions back (see the /etc permissions on the CD when you boot up), then reboot.
5. Ctrl+Alt+F2 might work, if you login as root.

Comment: Thanks, @Xen2050. Still working on my editing skills!

Comment: Method 3 worked like a charm! -Simple and easy.  I did in fact know root's password.  After logging-in to an Xfce desktop environment, I was able to open a terminal and execute `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc`. -Helped immediately, -at least in the sense that I now have access to my regular user account.  (~Thank you!)  I will now have to update/reinstall all kinds of software... -_-